# SVG created with JS is clipped

Tags: javascript, html, svg

This svg code:

```
<div style="width: 25%; height: 100%; position: relative; background-color: orange;">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 1 1" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="teal" style="pointer-events: all;">
    </circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

produces this image:

[image: teal circle in orange square]

And was generated with this code:

```
this.$el = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(this.$el);
this.$svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
this.$el.appendChild( this.$svg );
this.$circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
this.$svg.appendChild(this.$circle);

this.$el.style.width = '25%';
this.$el.style.height = '100%';
this.$el.style.position = 'relative';
this.$el.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';

this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewbox', '0 0 1 1');
this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '100%');
this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '100%');
this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid meet');

this.$circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', '50%');
this.$circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', '50%');
this.$circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', '50%');
this.$circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'teal');
```

However, when this code is run and populates the DOM, it renders like this:

[image: cropped teal circle in orange rectangle]

Copying and pasting the *exact same just generated SVG code* into the DOM renders the SVG as expected.  What is going on here?  How to get the dynamically generated SVG to render correctly?

Here is the issue on codepen:

http://codepen.io/jedierikb/pen/VPzpwj

---

To see the rendering problem, be sure to press 'Expand snippet' or 'Full Page':

```js
this.$el = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(this.$el);
this.$svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
this.$el.appendChild( this.$svg );
this.$circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
this.$svg.appendChild(this.$circle);

this.$el.style.width = '25%';
this.$el.style.height = '100%';
this.$el.style.position = 'relative';
this.$el.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';

this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewbox', '0 0 1 1');
this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '100%');
this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '100%');
this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid meet');

this.$circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', '50%');
this.$circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', '50%');
this.$circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', '50%');
this.$circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'teal');
```

```html
<div style="width: 25%; height: 100%; position: relative; background-color: orange;">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 1 1" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="teal" style="pointer-events: all;">
    </circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I see identical circles, displaying as expected on OSX Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit) from your code snippet

Comment: @haxxxton Hit ''expand snippet' or 'Full Screen'.  I am not sure why it renders correctly in the post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. Firstly, your percentage height is not actually doing anything because the parent elements (body and html) do not have a specified height. However, since this is consistent for both examples, this isn't the source of the disparity. You have a capitalization error in this line:

```
this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewbox', '0 0 1 1');
```

should be

```
this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewBox', '0 0 1 1');
```

See your example with this change made:

```js
this.$el = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(this.$el);
this.$svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
this.$el.appendChild( this.$svg );
this.$circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
this.$svg.appendChild(this.$circle);

this.$el.style.width = '25%';
this.$el.style.height = '100%';
this.$el.style.position = 'relative';
this.$el.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';

this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewBox', '0 0 1 1');
this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '100%');
this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '100%');
this.$svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid meet');

this.$circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', '50%');
this.$circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', '50%');
this.$circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', '50%');
this.$circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'teal');
```

```html
<div style="width: 25%; height: 100%; position: relative; background-color: orange;">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 1 1" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="teal" style="pointer-events: all;">
    </circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: interesting that the capitalization in the provided svg doesn't cause any problems -- only the one built by js.  why is that?

Comment: @jedierikb I suspect because (some browsers) correct capitalization of inline attributes when building the DOM. You can test this by doing something like `someEl.innerHTML = '<span cLasS="what"></span>'`. The resulting DOM node will be `<span class="what"></span>`. However, this does not happen if you are applying attributes directly to nodes using JS.

Comment: Now that I think of it, it's pretty bizarre that svg uses *case sensitive* camelcase attrs. Would love to hear some deeper explanation of how/why that transpired.